# creating custom products page based on new filters in prestashop 1.7 module

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have prestashop 1.7.2.4 installed.
I created a module with a controller, and connected to the `ModuleRoutes` hook in order to create my own specific route that actually works! :)

in general I created a new set of secondary categories in my prestashop module and I would like to create a products page that will only show the relevat products based on the 2nd category set.

so I created a box on the front page that will search by the 2nd categories sets, and then redirects to the proper friendly url that is catched by the `ModuleRoutes` hook and properly opens a.. clean page for now :)

how do I actually create a custom products page with cart and everything?
no idea how to move forward from here.

any information regarding the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You should add some others hooks to achieve the trick, as implements hooks like  actionBeforeCartUpdateQty actionCartSave actionCartSummary same for carrier ... etc. http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS17/Hooks+in+PrestaShop+1.7.x

Comment: @headmax - can't I use CategoryController instead of FrontController and override that it will use a custom set of catgory id ?

Comment: i'm confused because with hooks I can connect to events. I don't know how to display prestashop's components on my custom page (like cart icon.... specific products and so on)

Comment: yes you could extends `extends CategoryController` and initialized from `init()` and `initConent()` the parent class and customised this is for 19.x> https://digitaldisseny.com/es/blog/195-prestashop-different-layouts-per-category but is should be similar. But 1.7 is no longer fixed as we can show http://nemops.com/prestashop-1-7-failure/#.WfR1sxZb-MA may be a update by using click update module way ;).

Comment: I guess i a m in the same situation, and for the major stable new version you need to do major update by the hand you can also import export data clients easy but categories you need to **take care about the root category named** for this update, same for your modules : look at the version available from modules owners to do a good migrate job... for your own modules nothing to do is already adapted etc ...

Comment: I though I can extend ProductListingFrontControllerCore but a no go. i'm now clueless and in need for a solution!

Comment: Do you need to display only a list of custom products or do you need a different template as well?

Comment: @TheDrot - only custom products list based on an sql query from the page parameters. no need to change the template

Comment: I can't give you a specific answer as I'm not really familiar with 1.7, however I'd forget the custom controller and use the hooks that are available to you for customizing product list. [This](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/develop/classes/controller/ProductListingFrontController.php#L231) hook can be used to create your custom list by providing your own `ProductSearchProviderInterface`. [This](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/develop/src/Adapter/BestSales/BestSalesProductSearchProvider.php) is an example of how best sales list is created.

Comment: @TheDrot - thank you so much. investigating